# Uploading videos Rails/S3/Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have already gone through all the answers to make the upload of my video to S3 work but they do not work. I keep on getting the error uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::Aws.

I hope you could help me out on this one.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.4'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.0.1"
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.6'
gem "figaro"
```

**config\s3.yml**

```
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: xxx
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: xxx
    S3_BUCKET_NAME: xxx
```

**models\video.rb**

```
    class Video < ApplicationRecord

            has_attached_file :clip, styles: {
                        medium: {
                                  :geometry => "640x480",
                                  :format => 'mp4'
                        },
                        thumb: { :geometry => "160x120", 
                                    :format => 'jpeg', 
                                    :time => 10}
                         }, 

                         processors: [:transcoder],

                           :storage => :s3,
                           :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"


            validates_attachment :clip,
                     content_type: { content_type: ['application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/flv', 'video/x-flv']}


            before_post_process :skip_for_audio

            def skip_for_audio
                ! %w(audio/ogg application/ogg).include?(asset_content_type)
            end

            before_post_process :image?
            def image?
              !(data_content_type =~ /^image.*/).nil?
            end
end
```

**Videos_controller.rb**

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController


      def index
        @videos = Video.all
        @video = Video.order('created_at')
      end

      def new
         @video = Video.new
      end


      def create
        @video = Video.new(videos_params)
        if @video.save
          flash[:success] = "The step was added!"
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render 'New'
        end

        end 

        def destroy
            @video = Video.find(params[:id])
            @video.destroy
            flash[:success] = "The step was destroyed."
            redirect_to root_path
        end

        private

        def videos_params
            params.require(:video).permit(:title, :description, :clip)
        end




    end
```

**initilizers\paperclip.rb**

```
paperclip_defaults = Rails.application.config_for :paperclip
paperclip_defaults.symbolize_keys!

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge! paperclip_defaults
```

**initilizers\aws.rb**

```
AWS.config(
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)

S3_BUCKET =  AWS::S3.new.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET']]
```

Comment: what do your initializers for paperclip and AWS look like at?

Comment: this is the one for paperclip
paperclip_defaults = Rails.application.config_for :paperclip
paperclip_defaults.symbolize_keys!

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge! paperclip_defaults


while this is the one for aws
AWS.config(
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)

S3_BUCKET =  AWS::S3.new.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET']]

Comment: can you update your question with the paperclip defaults configuration?

Comment: I have just updated the questions with the two initilizers + the keys and the bucket are all stored in the s3.yml

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with your aws-sdk gem version. try this `gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your tried [this configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)?

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

.

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

.

Comment: I am actually follwoing your advice but now I receive this error 

' error while running command if command -v avprobe 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi: Command 'if command -v avprobe 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi' returned 1. Expected 0 Here is the command output: STDOUT: STDERR: -v was unexpected at this time. '

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with this error at all. Where are you getting it? do you have a github repo for this?

Comment: Yes - https://github.com/Stepeo/Redam - It would be great if you could explain me whats going on! :)

Comment: I've cloned the repo. The error you're having is: Av::UnableToDetect (Unable to detect any supported library): /// You need to install ffmpeg. To do so, install homebrew from: https://brew.sh/ and run these in your Terminal 1. brew link yasm 2. brew install ffmpeg /// Video is now transcoded but raises a missing New template. Good luck! ;)

Comment: I am not running on Mac, but on windows so I have downloaded scoop and installed ffmpeg but  the error still occurs. Maybe you have other settings that I dont have

Comment: I guess you've restarted the server before trying to upload a video again?  I'm also stuck on your app, the next error is a Rollback Transaction (Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 34496ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms) // ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Clip content type is invalid, Clip is invalid) after Successfully transcoded. Sorry, I can't help you any further.

Comment: That could be also for the file extension of the validation! I guess. Thank you very much for the help :)